# How can a malicious activity be controlled in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

How can a malicious activity be controlled in hyperledger fabric ?
Any links will be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Fabric is an implementation of the Blockchain. Blockchain guarantees safety because it is a distributed system. The information is replicated in different nodes in the network. So, if you changed one, the other nodes would realize.

On the other hand, a Blockchain is a chain composed by blocks that store transactions. Each block references to the previous one, so if you wanted to modify the data in one block, you should change all the blocks. And this is computationally very difficuatl, you should have more than the 51 % of computing capacity of the network.

You can read more about it [here](https://jfin-swufe.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40854-016-0046-5).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can control through put txt and a potential maximum per port or user per second.
2. Create a transaction fee which would limit what they are doing if they are taxing the network.
3. Kick them off the network.